Filtering my data frame is erasing my data frame despite correct number of rows
I have a dataframe of transactions (roughly 76K rows). Each row has a column called START_DATE which is when the transaction started.
I am trying to filter down to transactions with START_DATE > 1/1/2023.
I am doing this:
str(A_23$START_DATE) ##IT STARTS OUT AS A CHR
A_23$START_DATE <- as.Date(A_23$START_DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
str(A_23$START_DATE) ##THIS CONFIRMS IT IS A DATE
T_Date <- as.Date("2023-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d") ##USING A PLACEHOLDER VARIABLE TO VALIDATE STR()
str(T_Date) ##THIS CONFIRMS IT IS A DATE
A_23 <- A_23[A_23$START_DATE >= T_Date,] ##THIS CUTS THE DATAFRAME DOWN FROM 76K ROWS to 9K ROWS (IT WORKS)
head(A_23) ##EVERYTHING IS NA, THE ENTIRE FRAME

What am I doing wrong? Why is this causing all of my data to get erased but R knows how many rows?

Can you run dput(head(A_23$START_DATE)) before and after the 2nd line, and edit your question to include the resulting code? One possibility is that you have not correctly converted your data to valid Dates (e.g. maybe they're actually character formatted "YYYY/MM/DD" and so they evaluate NA with your code which is for "YYYY-MM-DD") so then the subsequent comparison doesn't work as you expect. We won't be able to help without a sample of the data.

Whoever edited my Q - how did you get the code to render like that?

I selected the code and clicked the {} button, which indents the text so that the site renders that block as code (gray background, monospace font).

Here is a possible solution:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

    df <- data.frame(
      start_date = c("1/2/2021","5/11/2020","1/2/2021","5/11/2020"),
      item = c("A","B","C","D")
    )
    
    df <- df |> 
      mutate(start_date = as_date(dmy(start_date)))
    
    
    # filter date
    date_filter <- df |> 
      filter(!start_date %in% ymd("2021-02-01")) 

date_filter



  start_date item
1 2020-11-05    B
2 2020-11-05    D

Hope this helps!

Filter works, but now I don't understand why filter works and base R doesn't. It's super weird. Any thoughts as to why filter doesn't error but base does?

That is because they are two different functions that are used differently. dplyr::filter() is used to subset data frames while base Filter() is used to handle vectors.

The OP is not using Filter, they are using base R bracket subsetting. I presume the issue is because OP did not successfully convert their text-as-date into the Date data format. lubridate's helper functions like dmy are more forgiving than base as.Date, which requires you to specify the incoming format correctly. dmy will read 1 Jan 2015 and 01-01-15 and 1/1/2015 but as.Date will expect you to specify the formats as %d %b %Y, %d-%m-%y, and %d/%m/%Y, respectively. OP code specifies %Y-%m-%dwhich would only work if the incoming data was like2015-01-01`; I bet it's not.

It's hard to say where something go wrong without a reproducible example. As others said in comments, maybe the date format is not right, and it could lead to NA values.
This following chunk give a small demonstration of a question asked in comments about the difference in base and dplyr::filter()
library(dplyr)

# Creating a dataframe of Date with a NA vaue
df = data.frame(x = as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2023-01-03",NA,"2023-01-05")))

# Base R subsetting: Comparing NA return NA
df[df$x>as.Date("2023-01-01"), ]
#> [1] "2023-01-03" NA           "2023-01-05"

# dplyr::filter() : NA are removed
df %>% filter(x>as.Date("2023-01-01"))
#>            x
#> 1 2023-01-03
#> 2 2023-01-05

Also, the dplyr::filter() documentation clearly specify:

Note that when a condition evaluates to NA the row will be dropped,
unlike base subsetting with [.

